# LaunchScreen.storyboard UIImageView issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, storyboard

I have a *.png image with transparent background. I want to display it on my LaunchScreen. The thing is that the image is invisible.

[image: There's an image in storyboard, but it's invisible on simulator.]]

If I change background color from white to say black, the whole UIImageView is black and there's no image I need to display.

[image: Changing background color of the image does not help.]

ImageSet RenderAs setting is set to original image.

How do I fix the issue? Thanks!

Comment: can you share the .png image?

Comment: @DiegoQ Sure: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjjhCAQnMKUBgqEPuvZtJWCtH6X04Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that problem is caused by "clear color" that is set as tint color for storyboard.